# What is the use of --clang=<path> and --addon-python=<python interpreter> in cppcheck?

Tags: cppcheck

What is the use of --clang= and --addon-python= in cppcheck? Please explain how to use these options with cppcheck??

Answer (score 1):

From the `--help` output:

```
    --clang=<path>       Experimental: Use Clang parser instead of the builtin Cppcheck
                         parser. Takes the executable as optional parameter and
                         defaults to `clang`. Cppcheck will run the given Clang
                         executable, import the Clang AST and convert it into
                         Cppcheck data. After that the normal Cppcheck analysis is
                         used. You must have the executable in PATH if no path is
                         given.
```

```
    --addon-python=<python interpreter>
                         You can specify the python interpreter either in the
                         addon json files or through this command line option.
                         If not present, Cppcheck will try "python3" first and
                         then "python".
```